# How to implement and perform app updates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

How to implement app updates? A lot of apps have an small red indicators on top of their app icons. Currently, I'm planning to submit the initial version of my app to the store but I'm not sure how to prepare it for updates. Do I need and how to implement:

1) notification for users that a newer version of my app is released.
2) configure app settings when submitting via itunes connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about app version updates (as in, a completely new version of the app that is deployed into the app store), then those little red indicators are automatically put there by the app store/iOS when you submit/release a newer version of your app.  You don't need to do anything manual to get them.

If you wanted, however, you could [implement push-notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) to customize this behavior (or more accurately, to add your own behavior on top of the default behavior).  You could, for instance, notify users that a new release is coming soon, or nag users who don't update in a timely fashion to get the latest version of your app, and so on.

Or if you happen to be talking about content updates that do not have/need a new version of the app software itself, then push-notifications are again the way to go.  You can send one out when there is new information available for your app, and add an appropriate indicator to your app icon when the update notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.  When your your next version of the app is available iOS will take care of showing the red indicator and user will be able to update the app.